# How do I cater for when a attribute is missing in a XSL template?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a XSL template:

```
  <!--Define the column widths for the schedule-->
  <xsl:template name="SetColumnWidths">
    <!--The widths in the column classes will add up to 100%-->
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="@NumberClasses=1">
        <colgroup>
          <col class="columnTime"/>
          <col class="columnTheme1Class"/>
          <col class="columnName"/>
        </colgroup>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="@NumberClasses=2">
        <colgroup>
          <col class="columnTime"/>
          <col class="columnTheme2Class"/>
          <col class="columnName"/>
          <col class="columnName"/>
        </colgroup>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="@NumberClasses=3">
        <colgroup>
          <col class="columnTime"/>
          <col class="columnTheme3Class"/>
          <col class="columnName"/>
          <col class="columnName"/>
          <col class="columnName"/>
        </colgroup>
      </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
```

I want to extend it so that, if there is no **NumberClasses** attribute that it does exactly the same as for **NumberClasses=1**.

How do I do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this expression:

```
<xsl:when test="not(@NumberClasses) or @NumberClasses = '1'">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `<xsl:otherwise>`

**Update** (because it seems not clear how this should work) even if the answer from Tim C fits better.

In my view it is always a god idea to have a `xsl:otherwise` in `xsl:choose` and if you do so it could also do the same as one of the  `xsl:when`.
In the question case it is even possible to remove the first when.
Therefore the following may work:

```
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="@NumberClasses=2">
    <colgroup>
      <col class="columnTime"/>
      <col class="columnTheme2Class"/>
      <col class="columnName"/>
      <col class="columnName"/>
    </colgroup>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:when test="@NumberClasses=3">
    <colgroup>
      <col class="columnTime"/>
      <col class="columnTheme3Class"/>
      <col class="columnName"/>
      <col class="columnName"/>
      <col class="columnName"/>
    </colgroup>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
    <colgroup>
      <col class="columnTime"/>
      <col class="columnTheme1Class"/>
      <col class="columnName"/>
    </colgroup>
  </xsl:otherwise>

</xsl:choose>
```

Comment: Please elaborate on how this answers the question (this answer was in the Low Quality Posts review queue).

Comment: @JAL I agree that the answer form Tim C is far better. But in my view it is always a god idea to have a xsl:otherwise in xsl:when  and if you do so it could also do the same as the when. In the question case it is even possible to remove the first when. So what is wrong?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. You are right in that I could use the xsl:otherwise approach as a default catch. And I would argue that that is probably good practice and as a side effect would solve my issue. That said, the other answer actually explained how to test if a attribute exists. So I will mark your answer as helpful! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered:

```
<xsl:template name="SetColumnWidths">
    <!--The widths in the column classes will add up to 100%-->
    <xsl:variable name="n" select="xs:integer((@NumberClasses, 1)[1])"/>
    <colgroup>
        <col class="columnTime"/>
        <col class="columnTheme{$n}Class"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="1 to $n">
            <col class="columnName"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </colgroup>
</xsl:template>
```

(Needs XSLT 2.0)

Comment: I don't think I can use XSLT 2.0 with the processor I am using.

Comment: If you're constrained to use XSLT 1.0 then you should say so in the question.

Comment: That is a valid point. Thanks for reminding me to state this in future.